# QGIS Can you use diagrams with the time controller?

Tags: qgis

I have a point layer in QGIS that I can animate with time controller. I can set the point symbology so that the point style changes over time. However, I have tried this using the diagrams in the layer properties (pie charts), and these stay fixed regardless. Is there a way to make the pie charts change with each set of records displayed?

Comment: A workaround would be rebuilding the diagrams using geometry generator symbology. Rather cumbersome, however, depending on the complexity of the visualization/data.